# D7 Search Form Template override

Tags: forms, search

Ok so this is my first D7 project. Im stuck with the Search Block. First there is no way of customizing the search form block template to make the the search form input field and button inline to be displayed in one row. Ok i can live with that. But i cant live with not at all being able to overwrite the search result template. Neither does the preprocess_search_results() work nor do i find a way to overwrite the template for the search results. All i find is suggestions for D6 which all do not work.

Can please somebody tell me how to override theses templates and i am not talking about the form_ hooks like form_alter. I do not want to design forms by endless PHP Arrays. I want to template.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to /modules/search/ to find the templates you want to override. Copy/paste them to the 'template' folder inside your 'theme' folder. Make sure you clear the caches so Drupal knows what you have done. Thats all there is to it.

Comment: ok i tried that also before but it didnt load my template. for some reason now it does. thanks